# Passing variables HTML form into email form (javascript,PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html

The website: [sms.ledeclick.org](http://sms.ledeclick.org)

It's up but not working proper as of now.

the left form sends a sms correctly;

the first field is the phone number variable, which is used to send the sms to in the javascript

the second field is the car brand field, used to fill a variable in the sms text (to personalize it)

ultimately, i need the second form to be transparent, even inexistant at some point, the only thing i need is to receive a email to my address after the 'send sms' button is pressed containing:

time;date;car brand;phone number; sms message.

with the phone number variable as the email title

for now, i am only trying to fill one variable 'inputname2' into the email, it is somewhat 'working' but the 'variable field' in the email stays blank

Left form's html & javascript:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="author" content="Jean-Philippe Théroux" />
 <meta name="description" content="Le Déclick OBNL (c) 2017" />

 <title>Donations d'autos - Envoi de SMS automatisés</title>
 </head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> 
 <body>
 <input type="text" id="userInput0" autofocus value = "" />
 <input type="text" id="userInput2" autofocus value = "" />
 <input type="submit" value="ENVOYER LE SMS" onclick="sendOutput();" /> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendOutput() {
    var accent = "'"            
    var inputtel = document.getElementById("userInput0").value;
    var inputname2 = document.getElementById("userInput2").value;
        var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr1.open('POST', 'https://platform.clickatell.com/messages', true);
        xhr1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr1.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bE7pWH27T2uy3RME5QXc8Q==');

        xhr1.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr1.readyState === 4 && xhr1.status === 200) {
                console.log('success');
            }
        };


 var data1 = JSON.stringify({
        'content': 'Objet: Votre véhicule à vendre sur Kijiji; Bonjour à vous, Le Déclick est un organisme de bienfaisance fondé en 2004 et dûment enregistré à l' + accent + 'ARC (860458835RR0001).  Nous souhaiterions faire l' + accent + 'acquisition de votre ' + inputname2 + ' en vous offrant, plutôt que de l' + accent+ 'argent, un reçu pour fin d' + accent + 'impôt donnant droit à un crédit remboursable de 52,8%. Nous utilisons comme évaluateur externe le Canadian Black Book.  Si vous le souhaitez nous pourrons, en quelques minutes, établir le montant du reçu. Merci d l' + accent + 'intérêt que vous porterez à cette offre pour un bonne cause, André Émond, Fondateur du Déclick, andre.emond@hotmail.com 514-943-7236', 
        'to': ['1' + inputtel+ ''], 'from': '1 450-868-1737'}
        );

xhr1.send(data1);


        alert("MESSAGE SMS ENVOYÉ!");
 function myJavascriptFunction() { 
 var javascriptVariable = "' + inputname2 +'";
 window.location.href = "send_form_email.php?name=" +           javascriptVariable; 
}

 alert ("working");


 return;

}

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

right form html:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" id="firstname" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30 autofocus value = """>
</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"">
<label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="email">Email Address *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="comments">Comments *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6">             </textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a     href="http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

PHP FILE (send_form_email.php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$inputname2 =  $_GET["imputname2"];

// E-Mail To:
$email_to = "theroux.jobs@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "MikeLovdal.com Form Feedback";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the    form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be         valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "^[a-z .'-]+$";
if(!eregi($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!eregi($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($inputname2)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
 ?>

 <!-- include your own success html here -->

 Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

 <? 
 }
 ?>
```

the received email:

fou@fou.com via c-panel2.cyberlogic.net 
4:38 AM (46 minutes ago)

to me 
Form details below.

First Name:(THE VARIABLE GOES HERE LET'S SAY)
Last Name: him
Email: fou@fou.com
Telephone: 123-333-3333
Comments: ohohohoh

Comment: Thanks to whoever for formatting the code in a proper way =)

Comment: basically i just need the 2 values of the left form to be written into a email sent to me, automatically after pushing the 'SEND SMS' would be marvellous